# Automatically select new elements on scroll

Tags: javascript

Let's say i want to select all `<a>` tags of a webpage (like Facebook or so). I'm doing this by:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Currently, i'm just running a function every second or so, that search for all a-tags and then processes these a-tags.

The problem is however:

- Newly added  tags (by scrolling), will *have to wait some time* before being discovered
- Old tags will be discovered every time.

I don't think this is very efficient as well. How can I make a function that selects *only* newly added elements, and processes them directly?

Any ideas on how to do this efficient?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: If i try this on Twitter.com f.e. on the id `react-root` it never prints something...

Comment: Use Mutation Observer that looks for changes to the DOM tree https://css-tricks.com/a-few-functional-uses-for-intersection-observer-to-know-when-an-element-is-in-view/

Answer (score 0):

let's say the `<a>` tags are under a `<div>` tag.
you can try add listener to the `<div>` and check are the tag name of event.target and 'a' same when it clicked.
like this:

```
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener(function(e){
  alert(e.target.tagName === "a");
  // and do anything you want...
}
```